# Having issues while downloading favicon using python script

Tags: python, html, favicon, web-crawler

I am using a script to crawl and download favicons from websites. Some sites gave me 2-3 favicon images of various sizes (16x16, 32x32) etc..embedded in the same image. When I try to use this image it is not displaying properly as a favicon. Is there anything that I can do to make sure I download a proper image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a feature of the ico file format. They're perfectly valid files, but you're going to need to process them with something that actually understands Windows Icon files.